# Django channels install failure in Windows 10

Tags: python, django, django-channels

**Here is the environment:**

- OS:windows 10
- Django:2.0rc
- Python:3.6
- pip:10.0.0
- visual studio community 2017

**And the error message:**

```
running build_ext
building 'twisted.test.raiser' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual 
C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

Command "c:\users\airy\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Airy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0a1gjuaj\\twisted\\
setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open) 
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
__file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Airy\AppData\Local\Temp
\pip-record-k1vjz5aa\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed 
--compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Airy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0a1gjuaj\twisted\
```

I have already installed the build tools following the link description but it still doesn't work. If someone has solved it, please tell me how to fixed it.

Comment: You're going to find that Windows is usually an afterthought with things like this. If you absolutely need to use Windows and can't use a virtual machine you can use the Windows subsystem from Linux or Cygwin.

Comment: thanks, i use conda now,btw i had tried in elementOS but still failed.

Comment: ElementaryOS? Im not familiar with ElementOS. Did you install python-dev and build essentials?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Download twisted from this [link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted).
Downloading `Twisted‑18.4.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl` worked for me because I'm using Python 3.6. Download the version according to the python that you use.
After you download Twisted from the given link, open up a `cmd` where the file is located and run `pip install Twisted‑18.4.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl`. pip will install Twisted from this file.
If you're doing it in a `virtualenv`, activate the `virtualenv` and install Twisted after that in the same process.
After that, you'll be able to install channels or whatever.

Comment: For anyone unsure, it looks like the Python version is in the file name as `cp<version>`. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm running Python 3.7 and cp37 is the only one that installed for me.

Comment: Getting this erro : 
Twisted-19.........whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: @rahim.nagori What platform are you on? What version of python are you using? Are you installing the corresponding version of Twisted?

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami 
I'm on win 10, py 3.8
yes

Comment: @rahim.nagori It might be a problem with py38 because for me jupyter notebook doesn't work with it. Maybe move down to py37 if it's an option for your project.

Answer (score 0):

if you followed the instructions as mention by @rahim.nagori and encounter the problem as mention by @DiptangsuGoswami. just download the 32bit version of twisted or 64bit (if what you used previously was 32bit). it worked for me!