# How can i create a notification system by django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

Is there anyway to create a notification system for my website by django without django channels.
If there is way how?

Comment: This question is too broad. What do you mean by a "notification" system?

Comment: Notification like, if i like your pic, instagram send you a notification...Like that type

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to send something (not in realtime) you can configure django to send emails.

If you don't need realtime you can save the notification in your DB like a model and inform the user with a badge somewhere in your front-end to invite him to read it.

But if you want realtime notification to clients on your app I think Websoket and Django Channels are the easier way.

Comment: channels says need visual c++ 14. can't solve the problem. thats why

Comment: But you really need real-time?
If your user can read it after change page you can save the message in database with a model and check if user have notification in your templates

If you want fix django-channel install see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50128924/django-channels-install-failure-in-windows-10)